# Make all Spring beans of a certain type request scoped

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a class and I want all objects of that type to be request scoped. In my Spring XML, I'm creating a list of such objects. It's very tedious and error-prone to have to set the scope and proxy mode for each one of these beans, so is there a way to make all beans of this type request scoped automatically?

I tried annotating the class with `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` but it didn't seem to work. Maybe the annotation is ignored when the bean is created via XML?

Here's what I have so far in XML:

```
<util:list>
    <bean class="com.test.MyClass" scope="request">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean value="Hello"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean class="com.test.MyClass" scope="request">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean value="Friend"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</util:list>
```

And my class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String value;

    public MyClass() { /* Default constructor */ }

    public MyClass(String value) {
        this.value = value;
}
```

Basically I am wondering if there is a way I can avoid having to add `scope="request"` and `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` to every bean of type MyClass and have them be request scoped automatically.

Comment: You can use an `abstract` bean but you'll still have to specify that in the XML for each `bean`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to annotate the class with @Component in addition with @Scope. You will need to add a configuration class with @Configuration and @ComponentScan within the package to allow the scanning of the component.